# I think she was right or I think she is right?

Tags: grammar

A lady says to her female friend Amelia that her boyfriend looks handsome. So when the boyfriend finally arrives to meet these ladies, how would Amelia admire the boyfriend saying that her friend was correct about him?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this depends on how much time has passed. Both can be correct given a context.

If the statement was made recently, **is/are** would be more correct. If a period of time had passed, **was/were** would be better.

If I would give an arbitrary number, I would say "recent" would be with in the day, or even stretching to within the week, however any longer would be **was/were**.

Also to complicate it a little more, if recent and said colloquially, often native English speakers would shorted the statement to, "My **friend's** correct" or "**You're** correct" rather than outright enunciating the word "is" and "are".

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Amelia could say "You were right. He _is_ handsome." **or**  "You were right when you said that he was handsome." Either would make sense.